# In VScode, how can I choose the priority between two autocompletion extensions? (e.g. Github-copilot & autoDocstring)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I am using VScode (version 1.80.2) with multiple extensions including github Copilot (v1.100.306) and autoDoctring (v0.6.1) which automatically generates a docstring template for python functions.
When typing """ (which starts a docstring in python) I sometimes get a suggestion from github Copilot (usually one sentence) and other times the option 'Generate Docstring' from the autoDocstring extension.
As the autoDocstring is more useful in this case, I would like to give it priority over the github Copilot extension, but without de-activating the copilot each time.
Thus, I am wondering if there is a way to set a priority between VScode autocompletion extensions?

While this contitutes rather an inconvenience than a major problem, I was searching for a solution and haven't found something so far. Currently, I try typing the """ with different speeds and sometimes get to the desired autoDocstring option and other times remain 'stuck' with the Copilot suggestion.

Comment: the completion providers are asked async for results, depending who gives results first get displayed first, maybe the order of extension activation might help but I don't know if you can control that, and maybe the extension adds a completion provider only when you open a file it can handle

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to define different [shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) keys for these two commands.  Or you can file a report request on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JialeDu, I think using a shortcut for autoDocstring is a great solution I haven't thought of before.

Comment: @Timo Thank you for your approval.  I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### As a workaround:

You can assign different [shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) keys to the two extended commands respectively.

[image]